# Xcode Icon dimensions don't meet size requirements

Tags: xcode, icons

Before you all get pissy about me posting this question again, let me explain myself!
I have been working on this problem for more than two days now, trying absolutely everything recommended on all the sites. I have spent hours searching through sites, each suggesting their own solution and all of them not working!

The problem is:
iPhone/iPod Touch: icon.png: icon dimensions (114 x 114) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

I even updated to all the lates OS X and updated Application Loader. My certificates are fine, it is just this damn icon thing preventing me from submitting! Please help!! Could we skype? Share my screen? I'll do anything! (not a reference to meatloaf) Please just help me submit my app!!!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But an icon with the size 114x114 and the name icon114.png into your project. Then put a icon with the size 57x57 and the name icon57.png into your project. Then set the icon files in your Info.plist.

Comment: I shed a tear for you dasdom, thank you so much for your help. I did what you suggested and it went right through with no problems! It's amazing, how did you ever come upon that solution?!

Comment: I started in the days when there was no retina display.

Comment: how do you set the icon files in your info.plist?